# Problems with malloc

Tags: c, memory, malloc, brk

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    char *p[10];
    
    for(int i =0 ; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        ssize_t msize = pow(2,i) * sizeof(char);
        p[i] = (char*)malloc(msize);
        printf("%p\n",sbrk(0));
    }
    printf("malloc done!\n");
    
    for(int i =0 ;i < 10; ++i)
    {
        free(p[i]);
    }

    exit(0);
}
```

The output like that:

```
0x55ffd4dd5000
0x55ffd4dd5000
0x55ffd4dd5000
0x55ffd4dd5000
0x55ffd4dd5000
0x55ffd4dd5000
0x55ffd4dd5000
0x55ffd4dd5000
0x55ffd4dd5000
0x55ffd4dd5000
malloc done!
```

When using `malloc()` to allocate the blocks of memory smaller than `MMAP_THRESHOLD` bytes, the glibc `malloc()` will use `sbrk()` or `brk()` to finish that. As known, both `brk()` and `sbrk()` will adjust the size of the heap.

So if I use `malloc()` to allocate the small(size < `MMAP_THRESHOLD`) memory block, the heap should be changed, But why does heap not change in this case?

Comment: If you want to add information to the question, then please [edit] the question. Please don't use comments for this, as comments should only be used to respond to other people's comments.

Comment: Please edit your question to explain *why* you think successive calls to `sbrk(0)` should return different values.

Comment: "*Why does "the program break" not change*". `malloc` implementations typically have a cache of blocks. It does not need to increase the heap for every malloc call.

Comment: most malloc implementations these days use mmap to get memory from the system, rather than brk/sbrk